# Any way to show the commands generated by a command containing 'find', 'xargs'?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, find, xargs

For example, if I have a command:

```
find . -name "*.png" |xargs -I{} sh -c "mycommand {}"
```

If I have a.png and b.png in the current folder, I want a way to show the following, but not execute them:

```
mycommand a.png
mycommand b.png
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Put an `echo` before `mycommand`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change that command to

```
find . -name "*.png" |xargs -I{} echo "mycommand {}"
```

If you just want to show the command before execute it, you could use `-t` option of `xargs`:

```
find . -name "*.png" |xargs -t -I{} sh -c "mycommand {}"
```

Comment: This works. I did not realize that echo here would expand '{}' to actual parameters.